SSMS 20.0 when open Replication Monitor, cannot add publisher to monitor replication
I have installed SSMS 20.0 on Windows 11. When I open Replication monitor, it should usually ask to add a publisher to monitor it. But its not showing an option to monitor a publisher. Lower version of SSMS 18 works good.is there something wrong with SSMS 20 ?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
